# Which Externals dll's are required by my application?

Tags: .net, dependency-management

Is there any way to know which dlls are required by a net assembly???. The program was built with some external libraries, but idont know what libraries was.

Comment: In what context? The question as it stands is too vague to answer.

Comment: Whatever DLLs that were in the Reference node.  Minus the ones whose types you didn't use at all.  Look with ildasm.exe at the manifest.

Comment: I edited my question for better explanation ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you debug the .NET assembly in Visual Studio, open the Debug: Modules window to see all the DLLs that are loaded by the process.

You should do a web search for DLL dependency walker.  This sort of tool shows the static dependencies between DLLs.  .NET assemblies are DLLs and should work fine with these sorts of tools.

Static analysis tools will not be able to tell you about any DLLs that are dynamically loaded at runtime (by LoadLibrary() etc).  A live debugger session will show you those.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could open the assembly in Reflector - if it opens it is a .Net assembly

Comment: If it is an unmanaged C++ dll using COM interop with a .NET assembly Refelctor will not open it and you will not be able to tell that it requires the .NET assembly.

Comment: @Oded - If you are only looking at one assembly, that would be correct. If you are going through a collection of assemblies, the COM-exposed one will open in Reflector.  Having to open each one individually might take time - I didn't say it was the best solution :)

Comment: yep, im sure is a net assemby